# Loading images so that it works in JAR-Files and NetBeans

Tags: java, image, executable-jar

I've got a problem with the jar file that's supposed to run the game i'm trying to create.
It's basicaly a major issue with the loading of Images so that it works in the Jar aswell as Netbeans' environment.

i'm currently using

```
imgIcon = new ImageIcon(Core.classLoader.getResource("Images/Boss1.png"));
img = imgIcon.getImage();
```

this works just fine 4 all my enemies the level background and the shots my various object fire. But if I try to use it on my player class the **JAR** file becomes **unexecutablem**, even thought it still works perfectly in NetBeans. So did i screw up in the Player or somewhere else because the Images seem to load with this particular code and only if it's also in the player the jar is unusable.

Player class to be seen here(I think it's got to be a problem in here that i overlooked over and over):

```
package Entity;

import Shots.PlayerShot;
import bullethellreloaded.Core;
import bullethellreloaded.Screen;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;



public class Player extends Entity{
public int x,y; // public used to make an easy mouse controll;
int xDirection, yDirection;
int health;
private Image img;
private ImageIcon imgIcon;
private Rectangle hitbox;
public static ArrayList shots;

public Player(){
    x = 250;
    y = 400;
    shots = new ArrayList();
    health = 5;
    imgIcon = new ImageIcon(Core.classLoader.getResource("Images/spaceship           (Redshrike,Stephen Challener).png"));
    img = imgIcon.getImage();
}



@Override
public void move(){

    x += xDirection;
    y += yDirection;
    // Wallcollision detection, needs to be ajusted for the size of the object.
    if(x <= 0)
        x = 0;
    if(x >= Screen.getScreenWidth())
        x = Screen.getScreenWidth();
    if(y <= 0)
        y = 0;
    if(y >= Screen.getScreenHeight())
        y = Screen.getScreenHeight();

}

public void setXDirection(int xdir){
    xDirection = xdir;
}
public void setYDirection(int ydir){
    yDirection = ydir;
}


@Override
public Image getImage(){
    return img;
}

@Override
public ImageIcon getImageIcon(){
    return imgIcon;
}

@Override
public int getX(){
    return x;
}

@Override
public int getY(){
    return y;
}

@Override
public Rectangle getHitbox(){
    return hitbox;
}

public static ArrayList getShots(){
    return shots;
}

public void fire(){
    PlayerShot shot = new PlayerShot(getX(), getY()-getImageIcon().getIconHeight()/2, 0, 1, 1,Core.classLoader.getResource("Images/PlayerShot.png"));
    shots.add(shot);
}



@Override
public void removeHitbox(){
    hitbox = null;
}

@Override
public Rectangle setHitbox(){
    int width = getImageIcon().getIconWidth();
    int height = getImageIcon().getIconHeight();
    hitbox = new Rectangle(getX()+width/2-5, getY()+height/2-5, 1, 1);
    return hitbox;
}

public void takeDamage(int dmg){
    health -= dmg;
}
public int getHealth(){
    return health;
}
```

drawn in my screen class which is an extended JFrame in the paintComponent that's invoked by the paint(doublebuffering and stuff^^)

in the following code segment:

```
    }else{
        g.drawImage(testlevel.getImage(),0,0,this);
        g.drawImage(player.getImage(),player.getX(),player.getY(),this);

        // painting the Score
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,14));
        g.drawString("Score: "+ Score.getScore(), getScreenWidth()-100, 50);
        // painting out the content of the ArrayLists shots, enemies, enemyShots
        try{
            for (int i = 0; i < Player.shots.size(); i++){
                PlayerShot s = (PlayerShot) Player.shots.get(i);      
                if (s.getDeleted() != true){
                    g.drawImage(s.getImage(), s.getX(), s.getY(), this);
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < Enemy.enemies.size(); i++){
                Enemy e = (Enemy) Enemy.enemies.get(i);      
                if (e.getDestroied() != true){
                    g.drawImage(e.getImage(), e.getX(), e.getY(), this);
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < Enemy.enemyShots.size(); i++){
                EnemyShot es = (EnemyShot) Enemy.enemyShots.get(i);      
                if (es.getDeleted() != true){
                    g.drawImage(es.getImage(), es.getX(), es.getY(), this);
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e){}
    }
    repaint();
}
```

I hope thats enough information, if that's not the case please let me know.

**EDIT:**

The question is more like is there another way that might work with my programm or what did i screw up to get this useless JAR thats not even starting.

changeing this (this path only works in netbeans the jar can't find it with this path)

```
    imgIcon = new ImageIcon("src/Images/spaceship           (Redshrike,Stephen Challener).png");
```

to this:

```
    imgIcon = new ImageIcon(Core.classLoader.getResource("Images/spaceship           (Redshrike,Stephen Challener).png"));
```

makes the JAR not runnable (not even a process in the background) whereas it worked just fine with the old path except the fact that the player didn't had an image.

Comment: have you checked your `jar` file contains the images?

Comment: yes the images are in a package called images inside the project(src) folder the so the jar is compiled with the images inside, but the fact tha tit crashes is more of a problem. Because i think it's got to work the code seems right but it results in an unusable jar as i said

Comment: Have you actually unzipped the jar file and checked?

Comment: is there any error message?

Comment: Nope, is while we're on it is there a way to run rhe JAR in a kind of debug mode thatmight work

Answer (score 0):

You should pack the resources into the final Jar.

For Eclipse there's a plugin called FatJar that does that (in newer Eclipse versions it's embedded as the option Export>Runnable Jar File).

Usually compilers will not pack resources into the bundle.

Comment: the Images are inside the JAR if thats what u mean but if there's no way to tell it that i should load these which i couldn't find after searching 4 quite a while.So I went with the classLoader that did its job good and loaded every image expected the one of the player class that makes the JAr useless and not working entirely it's nto even starting no more

Comment: Which exception are being thrown? (Execute the jar trough command line 'java -jar yourJar.jar' so you can read it)

Answer (score 0):

I found it out myself, its quite the ridiculous thing.
The Image's name seems to be to long 4 the classLoader if it's used in a jar shorting down the name of the Image let's the program run ^^

AnyWays thx to the ones trying to help me and to the JAR file that reminded me of looking into the simple stuff 1.

Snake